# Unhandled exception at 0x771CC7C9 (ntdll.dll)

Tags: c++, dynamic

**I have the following code in which an array is dynamically declared in a function. The following program compiles perfectly in Visual Studio 2013. However, during runtime the code breaks during printing the array, with the following error code:**

*Critical error detected c0000374
WaveEquation1D.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
First-chance exception at 0x771CC7C9 (ntdll.dll) in WaveEquation1D.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x771F8890).*

*Unhandled exception at 0x771CC7C9 (ntdll.dll) in WaveEquation1D.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x771F8890).*

**What is going on? Please help**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int solver(double i, double v, double c, double L, int Nx, double C1, double t);

int solver(double i, double v, double c, double L, int Nx, double C1, double t)
{
    double *msh = new double(Nx);
    double delta = L / Nx;

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= Nx; i++)
    {
        msh[i] = 0.0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= Nx; i++)
    {
        msh[i] += delta*count;
        count++;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i <= Nx; i++)
    {
        cout << msh[i] <<endl;
    }
    delete[] msh;



//  

    return 0;
}



int main()
{
    cout << "Hello"<<endl;
    int size;

    int j;
    j = solver(1, 0, 0, 20.0, 20, 0, 1);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This loop condition is wrong: `for (int i = 0; i <= Nx; i++)`. Your array has `Nx` elements, you are printing `Nx+1`

Answer (score 5):

```
double *msh = new double(Nx);
```

should be

```
double *msh = new double[Nx];
```

otherwise you're just allocating a pointer on 1 double.

And the condition is wrong as other users commented

```
for (int i = 0; i <= Nx; i++)
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < Nx; i++)
```

better solution: declare a vector of double

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<double> msh(Nx);  // instead of new double
```

no need to `delete`, of course, `vector` handles the deallocation automatically when variable goes out of scope.

and access your elements with `msh.at(i)` so if vector goes out of bounds an assertion is raised (performance suffers a bit, but bugs too)

Comment: You probably didn't notice the condition in `for` loops `i <= Nx;`, it should be `i < Nx`.